# 5+5% Equals 505% In Excel, Can Someone Explain The Maths Here?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here's the screenshot of formulae and the values:

[image: MS Excel]

Comment: 5 + 5% = 5 + 0.05 = 5.05. Shown in an Excel cell formatted as a “percentage” this gets displayed as 505%. One percent = 0.01 so 5 equals 500%. Tip: please put any images directly in you question, not as an external link.

Comment: @StarCat You should include your comment as an answer.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, done.

Comment: So do you need to calculate 5 * (1+5%) instead, which equals 5.25?

Comment: This is a mathematical problem, 5+0.05=5.05...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has a simple explanation:

One percent = 0.01 so 5 equals 500%.

5 + 5%  =  5 + 0.05  =  5.05

Shown in an Excel cell formatted as a “percentage” this gets displayed as **505%**.

Maybe an even simpler way to think about it is this:

- Whenever you place a “%” sign after a number, Excel will treat it like it’s *divided by 100*.
- When a cell is formatted to display a percentage, Excel will will display the value in the cell *multiplied by 100* (and followed by a “%” sign).

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio It’s not really about how Excel handles percentages — it couldn’t reasonably handle them any other way. 5% is just a different way of writing 0.05.

Comment: @MikeScott Understood.

Comment: Another non Excel way of looking at it  5% is 5 out of 100 or mathematically 5/100 or .05. So adding this to 5 gives you 5.05.  If you multiple this times 100% you get 505%

Comment: Nice one you get +10 ☺